# Empty Array sent by PHP contact form - pretty sure it's HTACCESS's fault

Tags: php

Here's the scenario: I have a contact form with few checkboxes:

```
<input type="text" name="cola[]" value="coke" />
<input type="text" name="cola[]" value="pepsi" />
<input type="text" name="cola[]" value="rc" />
```

Using jQuery's serialize, I have the data string sent to my `mailer.php` like so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://mydomain.com/mailer",
    data: dataString,
    success: function() {//some function}
});
```

Notice that I have had to omit the `.php` extension from the URL, due to a htaccess rewrite rule. If all 3 checkboxes are checked, the data string looks like: `&cola=coke&cola=pepsi&cola=rc`. I verified this using `console.log`.

`mailer.php` looks like this:

```
$cola = $_POST["cola"];
// other code
$message = "<p>" . $cola . "</p>";
// code to mail it out
```

However, upon successful mailing, the email body text just says "Array", instead of "cola, pepsi, rc".

I have a feeling it may be something to do with my rewrite conditions in my htaccess, which looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

My rewrite conditions are to remove any trailing `/` from the URL and wipe out the .php file extensions so that urls look like: `domain.com/pretty`

Can anybody help me diagnose why I'm getting the message "Array" instead of the array contents? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not your .htaccess the problem. In fact, $_POST['cola'] is an Array like this :

```
Array 
(
[0] => 'cola'
[1] => 'pepsi'
[2] => 'rc'
)
```

You need to loop through the Array and get your informations.

Hope this help.

Comment: you have 2 ways, a for, a foreach refer to this: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 2):

This is has nothing to do with htaccess, you're outputing the $cola array wrong!

Here is the correct way:

```
$cola = implode(', ', $cola);
$message = '<p>' . $cola . '</p>';
```

**Tip**: If you are not going to parse any variable inside a string in PHP, don't use the double quotes "", use the single quotes '' instead, it increases the performance since "" are parsed; more execution time.

Comment: Nope I've tested it myself it matters, and think about when you have a 500 characters need to be parsed a character by character until a $ is spotted, or just sending those characters to the out buffer and then send them out to the browser without parsing?

Comment: Hey, can you explain this part please? `$cola = implode(', ', $cola);` thanks!

Comment: Of course! implode is a function that takes an array as it's SECOND parameter and a glue :P as it's FIRST parameter, what it actually does is concatinate all of the array's elements and plug the glue in between, then returning the glued string, of course taking care not to add an additional glue after the last array element, you can always check of any php function by doing so php.net/manual/en/function.function-name.php replacing function-name , ex. http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: yes it's after the `$cola = $_POST['cola']` part, note that I am using $cola value and assigning to it at the same time.

Comment: @AhmedJolani, I've tested too. 100,000 iterations adding a 500 character string to an array - averages about 0.14 seconds each. PHP 5.4.0. What version are you using?

Comment: @MichaelRushton also PHP 5.4.0 actually I am a ZCE PHP5.3, adding a 500 character to an array? what do you mean by that? when you have this `$var = "blablablablabla..."` it's surely slower than this `$var = 'blablablablabla...'` double quoted string are parsed looking for an expression like so `{$variable} or $variable` while single quoted ones are not parsed, which one do you think is slower?!

Comment: I think they're the same speed because I've tested it. And it conforms with what http://phpbench.com reports.